# prevent user navigating to the next page using session

Tags: c#

I've designed a login page where user will get the otp once the user enter their email ID. In this case I want to stop the user directly navigating to the next page by using url. For example my otp page named as otp.aspx from this page without entering the otp if the user types `localhost/adminpanel.aspx` the page want to navigate back to index page. For this I've used session. But session values are not passing the page is navigating to index page if I gave otp also. Any help thanks in advance.

OTP page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblOTP.Text = Session["otp"].ToString();

    string alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string small_alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string numbers = "1234567890";
    Int32 digit = 8;
    string j = Convert.ToString(digit);
    string characters = numbers;
    characters += alphabets + small_alphabets + numbers;
    int length = int.Parse(j);
    string otp = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        string character = string.Empty;
        do
        {
            int index = new Random().Next(0, characters.Length);
            character = characters.ToCharArray()[index].ToString();
        } while (otp.IndexOf(character) != -1);
        otp += character;
    }
    vercod.Text = otp;
}

protected void btnOTP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vcode = vercod.Text;

    if (lblOTP.Text == txtOTP.Text)
    {
        Session["otpp"] = vcode;
        Response.Redirect("adminpanel.aspx");
    }
}
```

Adminpanel.aspx code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["otpp"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx", false);
    }

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.PopulateDropdown();
        }
    }
}
```